# ggplot2 geom_rug rescales unused axes - how do I stop this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm plotting a `geom_smooth` line and would like to add a rug.  The y variability is much larger than the mean values, so the y-scale gets reduced from the actual data range when plotting only the smooth lines.  When I add a rug to the bottom, it rescales the y axis as if there was a rug on the y axis as well, making it difficult to see the relationship of the smooth lines.

Example:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, color=cut)) + 
    geom_smooth(se=F, method='lm')
```

The above scales the y-axis to a range of about 0 to 3.

Adding the rug to the bottom only:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, color=cut)) + 
        geom_smooth(se=F, method='lm') + geom_rug(sides='b')
```

The y-axis is now scaled up to 5, even though nothing is being plotted above 3.

I'm aware that I can adjust the axis scales manually, but I would like to be able to do this dynamically for a large number of variables, and it seems like this behavior is incorrect. Thus, I assume I am using it incorrectly.  Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this *strange* behavior of y axis due to fact that carat values are up to 5. This can be seen by using `geom_point()`. When you use `geom_rug()` it looks on all points and plot rug for each actual value. Setting of `sided="b"` just hides rugs on y side but the space used for rugs on that side remains the same.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, color=cut)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_smooth(se=F, method='lm') + geom_rug()
```

[image]

You can zoom y axis to desired limits with `coord_cartesian()` and setting argument `ylim=`.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(y=carat, x=price, color=cut)) + 
  geom_smooth(se=F, method='lm') + geom_rug(sides='b')+
   coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,3))
```